# How do I provide different certificate to PHP's imap_open()?

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, imap

This works fine:

```php
imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', $user, $password);
```

And it fails without `/novalidate-cert`.

I have a different certificate placed somewhere else that works when I try to connect with `openssl` command to imap.

How do I tell `imap_open()` to use the cert in `/home/imap/googleRootCA.pem` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this from your local machine or on an actual server with a website?

Comment: from my local machine running Ubuntu 18

Comment: That will be why. Your home IP doesn't have an SSL cert. For testing locally use the `/novalidate-cert` and when you're on a real server with a real fully qualified domain name with TLS/SSL (HTTPS, eg. LetsEncrypt) then it will work as normal.

Comment: well.. it acts the same way on the live server. how can I find out what's the certificate being used?

Comment: Ah okay, so your domain is HTTPS (padlock icon) when you visit it? You can view the cert by clicking the padlock.. The SSL cert is set in your Apache VHosts file..

Comment: I'm not sure where, but PHP has a directory of trusted CA certs.  Part of setting up PHP and a Web Server will be making sure that's populated correctly.  On a linux machine, this is usually /etc/ssl and will be maintained by a ca-bundle package or similar.  It looks like Ubuntu calls this 'ca-certificates'.